# MapBox location.speed is always 0

Tags: android, mapbox, android-gps

I have the following problem.
I receive in my LocationChangeListeningCallback latitude and longitude but getting the speed is not possible. It is always 0.

Here is my code (I hope I have not omitted anything).

AndroidManidest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

build.gradle

```
//MapBox
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.6.2'
implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0')
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
    map = mapboxMap
    callback = LocationChangeListeningCallback()
    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
        enableLocationComponent(it)
    }
}
```

private inner class LocationChangeListeningCallback : LocationEngineCallback {
override fun onSuccess(result: LocationEngineResult?) {
result?.lastLocation ?: return
if (result.lastLocation != null){
val lat = result.lastLocation?.latitude!!
val lng = result.lastLocation?.longitude!!
val latLng = LatLng(lat, lng)

```
            if (result.lastLocation != null) {
                map.locationComponent.forceLocationUpdate(result.lastLocation)
                val position = CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(latLng)
                    .zoom(13.0)
                    .tilt(10.0)
                    .build()
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position))
                point = Point.fromLngLat(lng, lat)
                pointList.add(point)

                if(pointList.size>1) {
                    var location = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                    val results = FloatArray(5)
                    val lastlat = pointList[pointList.lastIndex - 1]
                    var xLng = lastlat.coordinates()[0]
                    var yLat = lastlat.coordinates()[1]
                    Location.distanceBetween(yLat, xLng, lat, lng, results)

                    //--> Here speed is always 0.0
                    if(location.hasSpeed())
                        speed = location.speed/18*5
                    else
                        speed = 0F
                    accDistance += results[0]

                    textViewDistance.text = "Distance in meters covered: " + accDistance + "\n" + "Current Velocity: " + speed
                } else {
                    textViewDistance.text = "Distance in meters covered: 0.0" + "\n" + "Current Velocity: 0"
                }

                map_view.getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback { mapboxMap ->
                    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) { style ->

                        // Create the LineString from the list of coordinates and then make a GeoJSON
                        // FeatureCollection so we can add the line to our map as a layer
                        style.addSource(
                            GeoJsonSource(
                                "line-source",
                                FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(
                                    arrayOf(
                                        Feature.fromGeometry(
                                            LineString.fromLngLats(pointList)
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )

                        // The layer properties for our line
                        style.addLayer(
                            LineLayer("linelayer", "line-source").withProperties(
                                PropertyFactory.lineWidth(3f),
                                PropertyFactory.lineColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
                            )
                        )
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onFailure(exception: Exception) {}
}
```

I hope somebody can help me.
I have not found anything on the Internet to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi, have you tried updating both libraries? as they are both pretty outdated

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your message. I was able to solve my problem some time later but I cannot remember the solution anymore.